# JQuery Plugin datepicker not working properly as per the documentation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker

This is my main html page called index.html. I have been using jquery plugin called datepicker. I checked everywhere about its documentation and i applied everything the net gave me but still it is not working.

These are the css pages that are there in the folder

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.css"/>
    <body>
        <input type="text" size="8" id="date"/>

//main jquery library

        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"/>

//jquery ui library

        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.js"/>

// my .js file for running datepicker

        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ui.js"/> 
    </body>

// my ui.js for using the datepicker function


$('#date').datepicker();
```

Answer (score 2):

Script tags are not self closing - you must close them with closing tags

Change your script tags like below

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ui.js"/>
```

to

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ui.js"></script>
```

From [mdn documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script)

> > Tag omission  - None, both the starting and ending tag are mandatory.

Comment: Then tag his answer as correct :)

Answer (score 0):

Open a dev console with F12 and see if all you assets are loading verify you have to correct paths

Comment: I Checked it but it is still not working.